# Regular expression for finding functions

Tags: java, c++, regex

All C++ functions are of the form

```
type name ( parameters ) { … }
```

To identify the regex, I'm using

```
regex = "...";
pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches())
{
    ...
}
```

I can only realistically search for the `type name (` part since I am using a line reader and function definitions can be multi-line and I'm not sure of what the regex would be. `.*\\b.*\\(` was my latest guess, but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is *not* a good idea... Think about, dunno... `template<typename T> std::vector<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type> my_function()`...

Comment: Generally you would not want to solve this issue using a regular expression parsed against the full text. Rather, you would first convert the input into tokens (identified by token type), and perform a regex-like match against the stream of token types. This is how most sane compiler parsers do it at least.

Comment: Actually the form of function is a little more complex.  see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you could reuse some existing C++ parser and save yourself hours of special cases handling.

Comment: I would look at `clang++ API`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no general regular expression that can match all function definitions.

The C++ grammar specification allows you to parenthesize the name of any variable as many times as you'd like. For example, you can write

```
 int ((((((a))))));
```

to declare a variable named `a`. This means that you can define functions like this:

```
void whyWouldYouDoThis(int (((((becauseICan)))))) {
   /* ... */
}
```

The problem with this is that it means that function declarations can have arbitrarily-complicated nesting of parentheses. You can prove that, in general, sets of strings that require keeping track of balanced parentheses cannot be matched by regular expressions (formally, that the language of those strings is not regular), and unfortunately this applies here.

This is definitely really contrived, but there are cases where you will see lots of nested parentheses. For example, consider this function:

```
void thisFunctionTakesACallback(void imACallbackFunction()) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Here, there's an extra layer of parentheses induced by the fact that the function argument is itself of function type. If *that* function took a callback, you could see something like this:

```
void thisFunctionTakesACallback(void soDoesThisOne(void imACallbackInACallback())) {

     /* ... */
}
```

If you're looking to find all function declarations, you might be better off using a parser and defining a grammar for what you're looking for, since these patterns are context-free. You could alternatively consider hooking into a compiler front-end (g++ can produce ASTs for you in the GIMPLE or GENERIC framework, for example) and using that to extract what you're looking for. That guarantees you won't miss anything.